# The new poor vs the newly poor

Tags: modifiers

a) Who will protect the privacy of the new poor?

b) Who will protect the privacy of the newly poor?

c) Who will protect the privacy of the very poor?

How to correctly modify the word "poor" in this context? Should I use an adjective or an adverb to modify it?

Answer (score 1):

"New" and "Newly" modify the phrase in different ways.  "Newly poor" modifies it as an adverb, it means "people who have recently become poor".  On the other hand "new" is an adjective.  In this case I'd understand it to mean a new social class.

> John and his family are newly poor. John had a good job until six months ago but when he was made redundant, he lost his house and now lives in a two-bedroom flat.

> The new poor are the young people in service industries. They have access to tech but often no equity.

"Very" is different in meaning to "new" or "newly"  You can be very poor and not newly poor nor part of "the new poor".

> John is not very poor. He still has a car, but he is increasingly dependent on short term loans.